# Ubuntu server does not show login prompt

Tags: server, 18.04, login

I have a machine running Ubuntu server 18.04.2 LTS headless with an RTX2080 TI. It has a single monitor and keyboard installed so that I can debug networking crashes I have been experiencing. The system boots and I am able to log in via SSH; however the screen freezes at 
`[OK] Reached target Multi-user-system.`

[image: See image]

I am able to SSH into the machine, so for kicks I tried tailing `/var/log/auth.log` and entering my username and password on the frozen ui. 2 seconds later, it showed up as a successful authentication on the log.  I have tried `CTL-ALT-F1` and various other key combos and I cannot get any response from the display.

Has anybody else seen anything like this? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling Ubuntu server, the issue disappeared.  The original problem seems to be a faulty PCIE Slot on the MB.  Moving the graphics card to a different slot fixed my problem.